# Paste information from program to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, clipboard

At work, we use a program to match certain data. I'm currently working on a solution to take those matches and insert them in a database. But in order to do this, I want the matchresults displayed in a datagridview. So far I've tried to use a code from [this awnser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116149/paste-from-excel-to-datagridview).

The problem that I'm having, is that when I paste the data from the matching program is that it only sets 5 columns, while it needs to be 7. It is caused by the fact that the last two cells of the first row contain no data.

Unfortunately I cannot change the data being copied to the clipboard, so I must change my pasting code accordingly.

The code I currently use is as follows:

```
    Const tab As Char = ChrW(9)
    Const lineFeed As Char = ChrW(10)
    Const carriageReturn As Char = ChrW(13)

    Dim generate As Boolean = True

    For Each line As String In Clipboard.GetText.Split({lineFeed, carriageReturn}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        Dim values() As String = line.Trim.Split({tab})

        If (generate) Then
            For cell As Integer = 0 To (values.Length - 1)
                DataGridView2.Columns.Add(String.Format("C{0}", cell), cell.ToString())
            Next
            generate = False
        End If

        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(values)

    Next
```

Could anyone help me with my problem? Any help would be much appreciated. If it would help, I could do without the first row, so if i could modify the clipboard string to ditch the first row, it would still work for my solution.

PS: the longer code provided by the mentioned solution also causes errors when pasting, so that's why I don't use the more elegant code provided.

Comment: You could just add the two missing columns after you have *pasted* the data. Btw, `=> Clipboard.GetText.Split(...)`: you could add `ToList()` to it, create the columns using the first element of the List, then remove the first line `[List].RemoveAt(0)` and use the List as the DataSource of your DGV. Btw2, doesn't this: `.Split({lineFeed, carriageReturn}, StringSplitOptions.None)` produce empty values?

Comment: Hmmm… if you know you ALWAYS need to add two empty columns to the grid, could you not merely change the ending loop value when adding the columns?  `For cell As Integer = 0 To (values.Length + 1)`

Comment: I've got it to work, it was indeed that I had to add two columns beforehand. Thank you both for pointing in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi and to @JohnG I was able to solve my question by simply adding two columns beforehand.